# Reusable Reposiotry.ts file for PostgreSQl operation with Sequelize ORM not working as expected when initialized from service

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have postgresql database with several tables in it. I created a reusable repository.ts file which when imported in a service file with the table Model passed to the constructor should be able to be used for operations with that specific table. Instead of creating a separate file for each table . But for some reason i can not use the create,update, findOne() ..etc methods with the created instance .

I have a model created like the following:

```
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  DataType,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import {IUserConfig} from "../../interfaces/user";
import {IBaseModel} from "../../interfaces/common";


@Table({ tableName: 'DeviceConfig', timestamps: false })
class UserConfig extends Model<IUserConfig> implements IBaseModel {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  id!: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Device)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  userId!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  name!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TEXT,
  })
  value!: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user!: User;
}

export default UserConfig;
```

IUserConfig interface declared:

```
export interface IDeviceConfig extends IBaseModel{
  deviceId: string;
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

IBaseModel:

```
export interface IBaseModel {
    id: string;
}
```

The Repository.ts file looks like :

```
import { Sequelize, Transaction } from 'sequelize';
import {IBaseModel} from "../interfaces/common";
import {Model} from "sequelize-typescript";
import User from "../db/models/user";

export default class Repository<T extends IBaseModel> {
  private entity: Model<T>;

  constructor(entity: Model) {
    console.warn('entity', entity)
    this.entity = entity;
  }
  public async create(model: any): Promise<any> {
      return await this.entity.create(model);
  }

  public async update(id: string, model: T): Promise<any> {
    return await this.entity.update({where: {id: id}}, model);
  }

  async findOneByOrgID(id: string): Promise<any | null> {
    return await this.entity.findOne({ where: { orgId: id } } );
  }

  public async findOneByPrimaryKey(id: any): Promise<any | null> {
    return await this.entity.findByPk(id);
  }

  public async findOneByKey(key: any, value: any): Promise<any | null> {
    return await this.entity.findOne({where: {[key]: value}});
  }


  public async delete(id: string, connection: Sequelize): Promise<any> {
    // SOFT DELETE
  }
}
```

the way i instanciate a service with the Repository instance for the needed table model :

```
class UserService {
private user: Repository<Device>;

  constructor(device: Repository<Device>) {
    this.user= device;
  }

  public async createRecord(data){
     this.user.create(data)
   }
}

export default UserService(new Repository<IUserConfig>(UserConfig))
```

and in the Reposiotry.ts file on method 'create'

```
public async create(model: any): Promise<any> {
      return await this.entity.create(model);
  }
```

'create' is underscored with red line and the error states:

```
TS2576: Property 'create' does not exist on type 'Model '. Did you mean to access the static member 'Model .create' instead?
```

this error shows for all methods:  create, udpate, delete, findAll, findByPk